# What is the difference between Bootstrap data-toggle vs data-bs-toggle attributes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**Context**

I am using a Bootstrap theme, and now I noticed, when the theme updated to Bootstrap 5 all data-toggle attributes were replaced with data-bs-toggle (except one, which element still works btw)

**Question**

What is the difference between Bootstrap data-toggle vs data-bs-toggle attributes?

Comment: I have seen the +15 flashing by ;) Is there anything missing?

Comment: Well, you catched it the right moment :-). Sorry for that, I realized my very first motivation to ask was, that I saw one remaining data-toggle in the updated code, (see in my original post) and was not clear  for me, it is intentionally different or just the developer missed it, or going forward is it backward compatible, so the question remained a bit open for me, so I wrote a comment there... Anyway I give the credit as answer, not only the upvote

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This comes fro [PR 31827](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/31827) and [commit 418f17e](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/418f17ee2b849dafdc39623ba2378df9229164a7) (Nov. 2020, bootstrap v5.0.0-beta1)

It fixes [issue 29479](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29479) "Add a namespace for data-* attribute?"

As explained in "[What’s New in Bootstrap 5 / Change in data attributes](https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-5-new-features-examples/#changeindataattributes)" from [Shahed Nasser](https://twitter.com/shahednasserr):

> Bootstrap 5 has changed the naming of the data attributes that are generally used by its components that use JavaScript as part of their functionality.
>
> Previously, most components that relied on some JavaScript functionalities would have data attributes starting with `data-`.
>
> In Bootstrap 5, data attributes for these components now start with `data-bs` to **easily namespace Bootstrap attributes**.

[Commit b38110a](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/b38110aa7de32ec71cec4f03342ff0c7f29f2991) concurs:

> Data attributes for all JavaScript plugins are now namespaced to **help distinguish Bootstrap functionality from third parties and your own code**.
> For example, we use `data-bs-toggle` instead of `data-toggle`.

Comment: Many thx. I've tried to look for (with no success) about backward compatibility and what is related: breaking change(s). Supposing there is no conflict with a 3rd party library, will data-toggle work in Bootstrap 5 or it this a breaking change and code must be updated to use data-bs-toggle?

Comment: @g.pickardou I haven't tested it, but I suspect BS5 means `data-bs-toggle` only. Which means some library would stop working (as in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34982). The point is: there is no more `data-toggle` in BS code: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?q=%22data-toggle%22&type=code