# bootstrap5 menu icon does not work in a page

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

my menu icon does not work when the user is on mobile device and it also not work when i inspect the page and try to run the page on responsive device. how can i fix this issue, so that when user visited the page he/she can be able to click on menu icon and see my nav-items?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <style>
    .navbar-brand h1{
      font: small-caps bolder 50px/1 sens-serif;
      color: dodgerblue;
    }

    h2{
      font: italic 1.2rem "Fira Sans" sens-serif;
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>Pondadb</h1></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="btn btn-success mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="{% url 'About' %}">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="btn btn-success mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="{% url 'Register' %}">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="btn btn-success mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Bootstrap data-toggle vs data-bs-toggle attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536277/what-is-the-difference-between-bootstrap-data-toggle-vs-data-bs-toggle-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Data attributes for all JavaScript plugins are now namespaced to help distinguish Bootstrap functionality from third parties and your own code. For example, we use `data-bs-toggle` instead of `data-toggle`.
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
  .navbar-brand h1 {
    font: small-caps bolder 50px/1 sens-serif;
    color: dodgerblue;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font: italic 1.2rem "Fira Sans" sens-serif;
    color: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <h1>Pondadb</h1>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="btn btn-success mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="{% url 'About' %}">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-success mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="{% url 'Register' %}">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-success mx-lg-2 mx-0 my-lg-0 my-2" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```